# Trap ORA errors in unix(HP-UX) shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

Script:

```
while read -r records
do
sErrors=`sqlplus /<<EOF
     WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE; 
     select id from table where name='"$records"';
     #if select succeeds then update
     update table set name='xyz';
     exit;
     EOF`

     if [[ $sErrors = "ORAsomenumber" ]] 
     then
         echo "Failed for $records with error:$sErrors">>logfile.log
     fi

done<file
```

I need to trap any error specific to select query(i.e. "NO DATA FOUND") or any
Database specific error that might occur for a record in a while loop and continue
without exit till the end of reading all records

**Oracle version : 10.2.0.5.0**

**Note: it is not mandatory to get specific ORA error only, any hint indicating the specific db error would be enough**

Thanks.

Comment: I fixed your formatting but you reverted it. Please remove the indenting from the paragraph after your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file：

```
name1 newname1
name2 newname2
name3 newname3
```

script：

```
#!/bin/sh

#set var
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/product/db_1/
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

ora_user="user"
ora_pwd="password"
ora_tns="dbtnsname"
log_file=/var/log/sql.log

while read user newname
do
sqlplus -S $ora_user/$ora_pwd@$ora_tns <<EOF  >>$log_file
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    DECLARE V_ID INT DEFAULT 0;
    BEGIN
      SELECT ID INTO V_ID FROM TABLE WHERE NAME = "$user";
      IF V_ID = 0 OR V_ID  IS NULL
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("FAILED FOR $user WITH ERROR:NOT DATA FOUND");
      ELSE
        UPDATE TABLE SET NAME="$newname" WHERE NAME = "$user";
        COMMIT;
      END IF;

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("FAILED FOR $USER WITH ERROR:"||SQLERRM);
    END;
/
EOF   #must top grid
done<file
```

Comment: Thanks merlin for mentioning this approach, really helped to resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

The way the sqlplus invoked is fine in your script, But string comparison does not work as it contains the whole error if you want to check for some particular error code (or) only some part of the string, Use grep command.
`echo $sErrors | grep "ORA-ERROR1" && echo "ORA-ERROR1 Found"`
`echo $sErrors | grep "ORA-ERROR2" && echo "ORA-ERROR2 Found"`

In the above case, it prints both grep output and the echo command output if it matches.

If you don't want the output to be printed, You can follow the below.
`echo $sErrors | grep "ORA-ERROR1" > /dev/null 2>&1`
`if [ $? -eq 0 ];then`
`echo "ORA-ERROR1 Found"`
`fi`